# Cannot find type SwiftUI 'Color' in scope

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I added an extension to `UIColor` with a quick conversion function to SwiftUI's `Color`.
It's very simple:

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

@available(iOS 13, macOS 10.15, *)
public extension UIColor {
    
    /// Converts the platform specific color object to a swiftUI color struct. 
    /// - Returns: Equivalent SwiftUI color
    func psoColor() -> Color {
        return Color(self)
    }
}
```

The compiler raises an error in **release** mode: *'Cannot find type 'Color' in scope'*.
But when compiling in **debug** mode I don't get that error.

The framework where it resides was originally developed in obj-c but I have been adding Swift clases with no problems since Swift 3. I'm currently using Swift 5.3 with Xcode 12.0. The deployment target is set to iOS 10.0 that's why I added the `@available` decorator.

I have no idea how to debug this, any help is greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

By adding `import UIKit` your problem will resolve in Swift 5

Comment: If you read the post, you can clearly see I already tried that

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with architecture, swiftUI is not available for armv7. When building in release mode, it included arm64 and armv7.

Reference:
[SwiftUI - “Use of undeclared type xxx” on deployment targets below or equal to iOS 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61954607/swiftui-use-of-undeclared-type-xxx-on-deployment-targets-below-or-equal-to-i)

Answer (score 0):

For example I have this in a custom extension file.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI


extension Color {
    init(hex: Int, opacity: Double = 1.0) {
        let red = Double((hex & 0xff0000) >> 16) / 255.0
        let green = Double((hex & 0xff00) >> 8) / 255.0
        let blue = Double((hex & 0xff) >> 0) / 255.0
        self.init(.sRGB, red: red, green: green, blue: blue, opacity: opacity)
    }
}
```

I can now use this in swiftUI like so.

```
Text("Hello World!")
    .background(Color(hex: 0xf5bc53))
```